# Cannot view image file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, takesscreenshot

I'm not sure why I cannot view the image file that I've screenshot using Selenium in Eclipse workspace. But if I copy and paste the link in the PC File Explorer, the file do exist. My problem now is i cannot view the image directly in the Eclipse apps. It appear as "Cross" icon only, no images shown. Is there any configuration i need to setup? Thanks.

[image: image file directory in package explorer]

[image: Cannot view image]

[image: exact image viewed in pc app (photos)]

Comment: Is this a valid JPG file? Can you view the JPG with another program? If yes, please add the image to your question.

Comment: Yes i can view the jpg with Photos app (desktop default app). i've added the image in the question

Comment: Can you also view the image with the Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact setup, but I suspect that you are somehow not closing the file when you write the screenshot to the folder. Of course that assumes that you are generating a screenshot with your program.

Comment: I tried to restart eclipse already, but still same